# How does this iterative method of calculating $\pi$ work?

Tags: approximation, pi

I found some code online that calculates $\pi$ to an arbitrary number of decimal places. I don't understand why the calculations work or how to find more information about the method used to derive them. I've spent a significant amount of time searching online for methods used to calculate $\pi$, including iterative methods, but I haven't found anything similar to this. The method is as follows.

To calculate $\pi$ to $1000$ decimal places, initialize $x_{1310} = 1$ and then calculate the following sequence.

$$x_n = {n^2\over x_{n+1}}+2n-1$$
$$\pi \approx {4\over x_1} $$

To achieve more than $1000$ digits of precision, initialize $x_n = 1$, where $n > 1310$, and calculate the sequence.

Why does this work? Is there a name for this method of calculating $\pi$?

Comment: have a look at [this site](http://pi314.net/eng/index.php) which is a collection of many interesting formulas, algorithms, etc. concerning $\pi$

Comment: @GCab Thanks, it also covers [continued fractions formulas](http://pi314.net/eng/brounker.php#fraccont), including one that matches the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is connected with the continued fraction for the arctangent function and the fact that $\pi=4\arctan 1$. See [this](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/10/). A different continued fraction for $\pi$ is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#A_continued_fraction_for_%CF%80); it is reported not to converge as quickly as the first one on the other web page.

People have written books on the convergence of continued fractions, and  I don't pretend to know the theory.  But it is clear to me that the expansion you refer to comes from a continued fraction expansion.

Comment: When I try to calculate $\pi$ using the formula from [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_continued_fraction_formula#A_continued_fraction_for_%CF%80), it seems to converge much slower than then method I asked about. The methods seem to be slightly different, or perhaps I'm doing something incorrectly.

Comment: There are different continued fraction expansions for $\pi$, and they do not converge equally quickly. The one you gave in your Q is the first one on http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/ArcTan/10/, with $z=1$, as you can see by how the squares and odd integers interlace.  I have edited my answer.